# Android : seekbar touch not working while playing music?

Tags: android, seekbar

Android seekbar is working fine it moves with the song. while touching the seekbar is not playing with the current position ..

My code is..

```
public class AudioPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnBack;
    static Button btnPause;
    Button btnNext;
    static Button btnPlay;
    static TextView textNowPlaying;
    static TextView textAlbumArtist;
    static TextView textComposer;
    static LinearLayout linearLayoutPlayer;
    SeekBar progressBar;
    static Context context;
    TextView textBufferDuration, textDuration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.audio_player);
        context = this;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        getViews();
        setListeners();
        progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), Mode.SRC_IN);
        PlayerConstants.PROGRESSBAR_HANDLER = new Handler(){
             @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                 Integer i[] = (Integer[])msg.obj;
                 textBufferDuration.setText(UtilFunctions.getDuration(i[0]));
                 textDuration.setText(UtilFunctions.getDuration(i[1]));
                 progressBar.setProgress(i[2]);
                }
        };
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Controls.previousControl(getApplicationContext());
            }
        });

        btnPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Controls.pauseControl(getApplicationContext());
            }
        });

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Controls.playControl(getApplicationContext());
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Controls.nextControl(getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void changeUI(){
        updateUI();
        changeButton();
    }

    private void getViews() {
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        textNowPlaying = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNowPlaying);
        linearLayoutPlayer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutPlayer);
        textAlbumArtist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAlbumArtist);
        textComposer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textComposer);
        progressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        textBufferDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBufferDuration);
        textDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDuration);
        textNowPlaying.setSelected(true);
        textAlbumArtist.setSelected(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        boolean isServiceRunning = UtilFunctions.isServiceRunning(SongService.class.getName(), getApplicationContext());
        if (isServiceRunning) {
            updateUI();
        }
        changeButton();
    }

    public static void changeButton() {
        if(PlayerConstants.SONG_PAUSED){
            btnPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private static void updateUI() {
        try{
            String songName = PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER).getTitle();
            String artist = PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER).getArtist();
            String album = PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER).getAlbum();
            String composer = PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER).getComposer();
            textNowPlaying.setText(songName);
            textAlbumArtist.setText(artist + " - " + album);
            if(composer != null && composer.length() > 0){
                textComposer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textComposer.setText(composer);
            }else{
                textComposer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            long albumId = PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER).getAlbumId();
            Bitmap albumArt = UtilFunctions.getAlbumart(context, albumId);
            if(albumArt != null){
                linearLayoutPlayer.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(albumArt));
            }else{
                linearLayoutPlayer.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(UtilFunctions.getDefaultAlbumArt(context)));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me to find the missing code in this .. Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code given in this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)